# NativeScript-Vue canvas and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: canvas, vue.js, nativescript, requestanimationframe

Is it possible to use canvas and `requestAnimationFrame()` in NativeScript-Vue ?

Comment: No, HTML5 / Browser apis like canvas are not available in {N} environment. Native app behaves quite different when it comes to animations. There are few built-in animation apis you could take a look - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation and there are several plugins in market place that supports few other variety of animations.

Comment: @Manoj Thank you!

Comment: You can still try to use setInterval ```mounted() {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
          this.updateTimer();
      }, 10);
      this.updateTimer();
    },```